firebase auth invalid email
I am not able to know how to show the user that his email or password is wrong. Although I have done everything but nothing happens. The code is below  ->
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        uid = auth.currentUser!!.uid
        var key = reference.child(uid).key.toString()
        if (auth.currentUser!!.isEmailVerified) {
            reference.child(uid)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@MainActivity,
                                "Sign in success.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            startActivity(
                                Intent(
                                    this@MainActivity,
                                    HomeActivity::class.java
                                )
                            )
                        } else {
                            addInDatabase(email)
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@MainActivity,
                                "Sign in success.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            startActivity(
                                Intent(
                                    this@MainActivity,
                                    HomeActivity::class.java
                                )
                            )

                        }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }
                })
        } else {
            auth.currentUser!!.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    verificationMailSentDialog()
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Some unknown error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        when (val exception=task.exception) {
            is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException -> {
                if (exception.errorCode == "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD") {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Incorrect password. Please try again.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            is FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException -> {
                if (exception.errorCode == "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND") {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"No user found with this email.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Error: ${exception?.message}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

Every time only one error code is shown that is ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL and I want to show the user what is incorrect , email or the password. Please try to help me out

You can check if the email exists in your user database before loggin in. If it exists, but fails to log in, you can tell the user that the password is incorrect. If the email doesnt exist, you can tell the user that their email could not be found. Firebase gives you INVALID_CREDENTIALS, as it's potentially violating privacy policy to tell any user that an email exists.

On projects created since September 2023 Firebase enabled protection against email enumeration attacks by default. This protection makes it impossible to distinguish between FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException and FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException (as that's precisely what would allow the attack).
